# connecting two satellites

Tags: artificial-satellite, spacecraft, design-alternative, astrodynamics, docking

How strong would my bond have to be if I wanted to closely connect (30cm - 1m link) two satellites on the same orbit in LEO? (I can move the satellites however I want to have them close to each other)
If I manage to tie my satellites could I envision to just use the propulsion of one of them?

Comment: what are you envisioning?  do you regularly bond objects that aren't in orbit?

Comment: The force between the satellites depends on the thruster and how the total mass is divided between the 2 satellites. F=ma and all that. Please include more details of the set-up.

Comment: @phil1008 it's not clear that your edit matches the intent of the OP's question.  I'm rolling it back.  Give the OP some time to clarify instead of jumping to conclusions.

Comment: There was an experiment done for the NOSS spy satellites with a tether.  Most of the info is classified, but a there's a lot of info out there people have managed to piece together.

Comment: Here is a link to the NOSS satobs overview, it has a (broken) link to information about the tether. https://www.satobs.org/noss.html

Comment: the short answer to your question is almost certainly yes--there's plenty of examples of using one satellite to move another once they're connected.  We want to know the details of what you mean by "bond" because it's simpler to do this with satellites that are docked. It's less simple if one has grabbed another with an arm (the arm is delicate). It's even less simple if they are connected with a tether, cable, or rope (the tether dynamics are extremely complicated)

Comment: I assume you are asking about the force or load on the connection when one of the satellites is accelerating? Simple example satellites A and B, hooks on each end of a tether are connected to loops attached to each satellite, is your question how much force is placed on these components when satellite A accelerates? If so it's the g-force times the mass of satellite B. Same answer for other types of connections. But there is no single answer for all situations as it depends on the mass of the second satellite and the acceleration. The amount of acceleration depends on what maneuvers are done.

Comment: if the question is "can I use one satellite to tow another with tether between 30cm and 1m in length" you have to consider whether the towing satellite's propulsion system plume will hit the towed satellite

Answer (score -1):

Over such a short distance you can determine the force between two satellites connected by a tether using

$$F = \mu m(1/r_1^2-1/r_2^2)$$

where

$F$ is the force between the satellites and the minimum strength for you bond,

$\mu $ is the standard gravitational parameter (3.986004418E14 $m^3/s^2$ for Earth),

$m$ is the mass of one satellite (let's assume 1000 kg),

$r_1$ is the distance from the center of the planet to the lower satellite (assume 6,378,100+400,000 m), and

$r_2$ is the distance from the center of the planet to the upper satellite (assume 6,378,100+400,001 m)

...to figure out the difference in the difference in gravitational force on the two satellites.

So, (if I did my math right) the force between them will be 2.56 milliNewtons.

This is pretty small. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster#:%7E:text=Ion%20thrusters%20in%20operation%20typically,N%20(1.1%20lbf).)...

> Ion thrusters in operation typically consume 1–7 kW of power, have exhaust velocities around 20–50 km/s (Isp 2000–5000 s), and possess thrusts of 25–250 mN.

I don't think you could use the thrusters on just one satellite and expect tidal forces to stabilize the pair - at least not with just 1 m of separation.

Comment: I think you used the wrong formula. F= G*M*m /r^2 calculates the force of gravitational attraction between two objects. If you have the mass of the planet as M and the mass of the satellite as m, then you are calculating the force of gravity between the planet and satellite. Also where did you get the value 2.56 milliNewtons? The Op didn’t give any mass values of the satellites. The only value given was the distance between the satellites. So if you use that as r, you then calculated the gravitational pull between the 2 satellites. But even with r, you still need a value for the mass.

Comment: Look closer....

Comment: best practice is to use $\mu$, which we know more precisely than $G$ or $M$ individually

Comment: Good tip - did not know that!

Comment: @phil1008 there is something fundamentally wrong about your answer. In the formula you provided, one can calculate the force between the satellite and Earth (if the distance between Earth and the satellite is also provided), however the force of Earth gravity on a 1000kg satellite is nowhere near 2.56 milliNewtons. That value is probably off by multiple magnitudes. Can you atleast say what you calculated there? The force between the 2 satellites maybe? Or the force between the satellite and Earth (and give the distance) otherwise it seems like this value comes from nowhere

Comment: @phil1008 Using the information provided, the answers I get are quite different. F = G*M*m/r² = μ * m/r². So μ =3.986004418 * 10^14 m3/s2, mass of the satellite = 1000kg, and since r isn't given and the satellite is in LEO (anywhere from 0-600km), I will assume that the satellite is orbiting at 300km (even though the satellite might not be exactly there) and Earth's radius is about 6378km. This means F = 3.986004418 10^14 m3/s2 * 1000kg / ((6378 + 300) * 10³ m)² and then F = 8936.1N = 8,9kN. That is quite different from your 2.56 milliNewtons.

Comment: @phil1008 You mention the force "between them" will be 2.56 milliNewtons. So assuming "between them" means between the 2 satellites and not the satellite and the Earth, then that means that you cannot use μ since the mass of Earth is then irrelevant. So F = G*M*m/r². So G = 6.673 * 10^-11. M = m since both satellite = 1000kg or also just m² = 1000²kg². and r = either 0.3 m or 1 m. I will the calculation for both. So F1 =  6.673 * 10^-11 N*m^2/kg^2 * 1000² kg² / 0,3²m² = 7,414 * 10^-4N. and F2 = 6.673 * 10^-11 N*m^2/kg^2 * 1000² kg² / 1²m² = 6.7 * 10^-5N.

Comment: @phil1008 out of all 3 scenarios where 1, the 2.56 milli Newtons is the force between the satellite and the planet, or 2 the 2.56 milli Newtons is the force between the 2 satellites where they are 0.3m apart or 3 where the 2.56 milli Newtons is the force between the 2 satellite with a distance of 1m. So the closest value I got to the 2.56 milli Newtons is in scenario 2 where it is the force between the satellites with a distance of about 0.3 meters, but even there your value is about a whole magnitude off

Comment: I reviewed everything and I did spot that I accidentally added a minus sign to the value of the exponent of the standard gravitational parameter when I made an edit after Erin Anne's comment, but this did not affect my result. I made some edits to clarify things better. My Excel formula is: F=GravitationalConstant*MEarth*MSat*(1/((RadiusEarth+AltSat1)^2)-1/((RadiusEarth+AltSat2)^2))*1000    mN

Comment: @phil1008 I see your mistake. You are trying to calculate the force between the 2 satellites by subtracting the distance between the first satellite and the center of the Earth to the second satellite and the center of the Earth. However, your formula faces some issues because the distance is squared. So what you are calculating is the first distance squared minus the second distanced squared and that is giving you the wrong results. In your 2 values 6 778 100 and 6 778 101 there is a 1m difference. But if one squares both and subtracts them, then there is a difference of 13 556 201m

Comment: @phil1008 Since you used the value the mass of Earth and the mass of the satellite you are calculating the force the Earth has on a satellite at 13 556 201m, but in addition I see you multiplied the whole thing with 1000 at the end of your formula. Is this because of the mass of the second satellite? If that is the case, then there is an issue with it because then you are trying to calculate the force of a 3 body system for a formula used in a 2 body system.

Comment: I am having an issue though of trying to figure out what exactly you are trying to calculate. I think you tried to calculate the force between the 2 satellite by calculating the force between Earth and the first one and Earth and the second one and then subtracting the 2 values, but the way you calculated it is wrong. If you want to calculate like that, then you should first calculate the the force individually and then subtract it. You cannot subtract the squared radius from another squared radius since it will give the wrong values.

Comment: The easiest way of calculating the gravitational force between the 2 satellites, if that is what you are trying to calculate, is to just use the formula F = G*M*m/r² and use the value 1000kg for both "m" since you are just trying to calculating the force between the satellites and not the force between Earth and the satellite. Then for r just use  either 1 m or 0,3m as the distance between the satellites. Then that will save  a lot of unnecessary subtracting and will avoid issues which you currently have in the formula. If you are trying to calculate something else, please say so.

Comment: The force between the two satellites we are estimating here is not their mutual gravitational attraction (that would be really tiny), but rather the tidal forces acting on them because they are in orbit around Earth. If the question wasn't closed, I would add more to explain why I think the formula I provided for that is correct. I don't think it should have been closed as it was clearly a good, thought-provoking, question, but ca la vie.

Comment: @phil1008 we don't close questions as a penalty, we close questions when they're unclear so that people don't add answers to them that don't actually apply to the question. Having clear questions and clear answers to those questions is what the site is about. Feel free to continue explaining why you think your answer is correct--it may well be!  We can't know until the OP weighs in again. If (as I suspect) you answered a different question instead, you can still ask that question and answer it yourself if you think it's useful to put out there.

Comment: Yeah, I had previously thought of a similar idea that sounded a lot like what the OP was asking about, so, to me, it seemed like what he was asking about was clear enough, but it just needed lots of grammatical touch-ups. But that could all have been biased by my own pre-existing idea.